# I cannot retrieve the data passed to a Activity with putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a minor problem that I'm stuck. The problem is that I had passed a id with the code below.

```
Intent i = new Intent(First.this,Second.class);
i.putExtra("classification_id","3");
```

However, when I try to get the parameter of 3 with the code below I get the result of -1 when I check it in the debug mode.

```
if(intent.getExtras().getString("classification_id")!=null){
        classId = intent.getExtras().getString("classification_id");
    }else{
        classId = "1";
    }
```

Actually I want to use this parameter to set it into a url to get the json data to get the json data . But Is this a right way? Or is it a bad practice to set the String int into a url? Ex. `"www.test.test/myid?="+classId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the intent coming from ? There are `getIntent()` or Intent coming from methods like `onNewIntent()`

Also I think this is shorter

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("classification_id")) {
    String classId = getIntent().getStringExtra("classification_id");
}
```

As for inserting String into url, you will be overwhelmed if there are many parameters (btw, I think this is a wrong format: www.example.test/myid?=classId maybe this is what you want www.example.com/test?myid=classId ). So we can do

```
private static final String URL="https://www.example.com";
private static final String PATH = "test";
private static final String PARAM_MYID = "myid";

public static String buildMyUrl(String id){
    Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse(URL).buildUpon();
    b.path(PATH);   
    b.appendQueryParameter(PARAM_MYID, id);
    b.build();
    return b.toString();
}
```